# Microsoft Office Communicator Automation API 2007 and Receiving Instant Messages

Tags: office-communicator

Does anyone know how to read the contents of an instant message?

Comment: If you're happy with the answer below, could you mark it as Accepted, to help anyone else browsing these questions? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Communicator Automation API (as opposed to the [Unified Comms Client API](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=82c468da-3294-4ca9-bbcc-d455cfd06af2&displaylang=en)), and want to get the conversation text history from the conversation window, then [George Durzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36057/george-durzi) has an excellent [blog post](http://blogs.claritycon.com/georgedurzi/2008/02/18/extracting-im-conversation-text-in-office-communicator-sdk/) on this.

The basic idea is that you capture the [OnIMWindowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb758791(office.12).aspx) event, then poll the [History](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb758708(office.12).aspx) property of the window, looking for changes.